# Correct setting for finding ERROR in logs filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

in AWS I have a filter

which checks if the word 'error' appears in the log.

```
const adminErrorFilter = new logs.MetricFilter(this, 'admin-metric-error-filter', {
  logGroup: props!.adminLogGroup,
  metricNamespace: 'my-dev-log
  metricName: 'admin-error',
  filterPattern: logs.FilterPattern.anyTerm("error","Error","ERROR"),
  metricValue: "1",
});
```

Then I set up an alarm for these metrics

```
const adminErrorAlarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'admin-error-alarm', {
  alarmName: 'my-alarm',
  metric: adminErrorFilter.metric(),
  threshold: 1,
  evaluationPeriods: 1,
});
```

However, these metrics only show the data when the error occurs, other than that, it doesn't show anything. So consequently, the alarm status is always `Insufficient data` not `OK`.

Is it the correct setting?

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error logs will be published to CloudWatch only when something goes wrong in the system. If CloudWatch doesn't receive any error logs, the CloudWatch alarm stays in the `Insufficient data` state, which is its default behavior.

If you prefer to consider the missing data points as an `OK` state of the system, you need to instruct the CloudWatch alarm to treat them as such.

To configure this, you can utilize the `treatMissingData` field to specify how the missing data points should be treated. You can choose any one of the following options: `BREACHING`, `NOT_BREACHING`, `IGNORE`, or `MISSING`. However, in your case, **NOT_BREACHING** is the more appropriate choice.

For more information on how to use the `treatMissingData` field, refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.TreatMissingData.html#members) page.

Comment: Thank you `treatMissingData` is the perfectly what I want. thank you very much!